# How to take url param and use it as filter for data

Tags: python, django

I'm just getting into Python/Django and I've managed to build an API to return all items in a DB table but I want to be able to filter the data through a parameter used in the GET request. I want to be able to return data based on the 'Author' id that is a number

I've built this based on the documentation:

**View.py**

```
class AllTweets(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        tweets = Tweet.objects.all()
        data = TweetSerializer(tweets, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
```

**URLs.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('restricted/', restricted),
    path('create/', TweetAPIView.as_view(), name="tweet-create"),
    path('list/', AllTweets.as_view(), name="tweet-list")
 ]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tweets")
    tweet_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add author_id parameter to your route:

```
path('list/<int:author_id>', AllTweets.as_view(), name="tweet-list")
```

After that you can get the parameter and filter with it:

```
class AllTweets(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request, author_id=None): # set as None for optional parameter
       if author_id != None:
           tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(author_id=author_id)
       else:
           tweets = Tweet.objects.all()
       data = TweetSerializer(tweets, many=True).data
       return Response(data)
```